# C++ template name used without template parameter

Tags: c++

I had been using "`const ObjArray&`" as the argument for the ObjArray template without thinking about it.  It seems to work fine but it looked off when I read it again.   Shouldn't it be "`const ObjArray<T> &`"?  Is it OK to refer to template name without the parameter?  Does it work below just because it is declared inline that compiler assumes T?

```
template <class T>
class ObjArray : public BArray
{
public:
    inline ObjArray() :
        BArray(sizeof(T), NULL)
    {
    }

    inline ObjArray(const ObjArray& src) :
        BArray(sizeof(T), NULL)
    {
        copyFrom((ObjArray&)src);
    }

    inline ObjArray(ObjArray& src) :
        BArray(sizeof(T), NULL)
    {
        copyFrom(src);
    }
    ...
};
```

Comment: It is OK inside of the class definition.

Comment: A class name is visible inside its own definition. This is called "class name injection". For class templates, the template name when not followed by template arguments is considered the injected class name. So yes, it's OK to use just `ObjArray` inside the definition of `ObjArray`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that usage is correct: Inside a class template, the class name refers to that instance of the template, so the template parameter is not neccesary:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    foo( const foo& ); //Copy ctor. foo is the same as foo<T>
};
```

This behaviour is well defined in the point ***14.6.1 Locally declared names*** of the Standard (Emphasis mine):

> **14.6.1 Locally declared names [temp.local]**
>   Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an injected-class-name
>   (Clause 9). **The injected-class-name can be used with or without a
>   template-argument-list. When it is used without a
>   template-argument-list, it is equivalent to the injected-class-name
>   followed by the template-parameters of the class template enclosed in
>   <>**. When it is used with a template-argument-list, it refers to the
>   specified class template specialization, which could be the current
>   specialization or another specialization.

Note that syntax is just an alias of the current template instance. If you need the same template with other parameter you need to specify it explicitly, with the classic syntax. For example:

```
template<typename U>
operator foo<U>() const //Implicit conversion to other instance of the template
{
    return ...;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct c++ syntax. Regarding your question about it being inline, you could write it like this outside of the class declaration:

```
template<typename T>
foo<T>::foo(const foo&)
{}
```

And it would still be correct. Notice only the first foo carries the template parameter explicitly. Once it has been specified, the context is completely defined, and now you can use foo as a perfectly legal class name, so the `foo` parameter will refer to `foo<T>` automatically.