# How does this typedef work?

Tags: c++

I am watching this cpp lightning talk [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uIyl_tDMkM)
there it shows this snippet of code at 0:37

```
template<typename T, typename cleanup = QScopedPointerDeleter<T>>
class QScopedPointer{

typedef T *QScopedPointer::*RestrictedBool; // how does this work? 
                           //why not QScopedPointer<T> since QScopedPointer is a template?

public:
inline operator RestrictedBool() const 
 {
  return isNull()? Q_NULLPTR : &QScopedPointer::d;
 }

 inline bool isNull() const{ return !d;}

protected:
 T *d;
};
```

I am having a hard time understanding `typedef T *QScopedPointer::*RestrictedBool;`, what does it mean?

I have created a similar class `F`, but it doesn't compile, what's the difference between the two typedefs in `class QScopedPointer` and in `class F`?

```
 template<typename T>
 class F{
  typedef T *F::*bool;
  public:
   operator bool(){return true;}
 };
```

Comment: Pro tip: look at the value being stored using that type: `&QScopedPointer::d` is a pointer to a member pointer. Also note that the syntax for `typedef` is `typedef <declaration>`. Note `RestrictedBool` is the new name, and you can't use `bool` as the new name in a typedef. You also don't need class template parameters within its own class definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
typedef T *QScopedPointer::*RestrictedBool;
```

This can be made clear a little bit when we move the stars around:

```
typedef T* QScopedPointer::* RestrictedBool;
//      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//       the type             the alias
```

In C++11 we would write this we more clearly as

```
using RestrictedBool = T* QScopedPointer::*;
```

`RestrictedBool` here is declared as a type alias of `T* QScopedPointer::*`. So `typedef T *F::bool` fails because you can't redefine `bool` :) The name is quite misleading because the type is not really a boolean.

The type `T* QScopedPointer::*` is a **pointer-to-member** type. This type here accepts any `T*` members in the `QScopedPointer<T, cleanup>` class, so e.g. we see

```
class QScopedPointer {
    operator RestrictedBool() const {
//           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//            this function returns a `RestrictedBool` = `T* QScopedPointer::*`
        return isNull()? Q_NULLPTR : &QScopedPointer::d;
//                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//                                    and this expression has type `T* QScopedPointer::*`
    }

    T *d;
//  ^~~
//   the `d` member has type `T*` in the `QScopedPointer` class.
};
```

---

> why not `QScopedPointer<T>` since `QScopedPointer` is a template?

Inside `QScopedPointer<T, cleanup>`, the class name `QScopedPointer` can be used in place of `QScopedPointer<T, cleanup>`. This is called *locally declared names*. See  [C++ template name used without template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045559/c-template-name-used-without-template-parameter)  for detail.